# Is there a way to Amplify & Adjust Sound Output in my Mobile Application for Deaf Peoples?

Tags: android, audio, volume, soundpool

I'm planning to develop a mobile application for people having hearing problems (not fully deaf), the idea is that the person with hearing loss will plug in his/her headphones into the phone, and the app will take input from the microphone and amplify it a lot & adjust the output, and enable the person to hear.

What packages/libraries are available, & should I go with Flutter or Native Android Development?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to implement actually exists. It's [Sound Amplifier](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/9157755?hl=en) by Google.

We can suggest libraries for you to use, but you will have to be more specific about the tasks you want to complete in order for us to suggest the appropriate available library for each task. So, I suggest that you firstly design the implementation you want to achieve and then find the tools to do so.

This also applies to your next question about choosing between flutter or native. Obviously, the first comparison point between them is that with flutter you create an app available in more platforms such as IOS, while native targets only android devices. So, you must first decide what is your final goal and then compare your options and choose the most appropriate.